# how to convert a python dataframe into nested json and save it locally

Tags: python, json

I have a dataframe from my python code:

```
 emp_id   skillset  experience  emp_name department
0    1120       java           7      Gary   Lobortis
1    1120     python           1      Gary   Lobortis
2    1120  Analytics           7      Gary   Lobortis
3    1122     Oracle           3  Prescott      Velit
4    1129        AWS           7     Kevin       Sed 
5    1122       java           3  Prescott      Velit
```

See the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EipI9.jpg) of the resulting table:

I want the nested JSON output from this data frame.

Comment: show us your effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of your DataFrame is `df`, the following should give you what you need.

```
import json

j = (df.groupby(['emp_id','emp_name','department'], as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda x: x[['skillset','experience']].to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'skills'})
       .to_json(orient='records'))


print(json.dumps(json.loads(j), indent=2, sort_keys=False))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "emp_id": 1120,
    "emp_name": "Gary",
    "department": "Lobortis",
    "skills": [
      {
        "skillset": "java",
        "experience": 7
      },
      {
        "skillset": "python",
        "experience": 1
      },
      {
        "skillset": "Analytics",
        "experience": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "emp_id": 1122,
    "emp_name": "Prescott",
    "department": "Velit",
    "skills": [
      {
        "skillset": "Oracle",
        "experience": 3
      },
      {
        "skillset": "java",
        "experience": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "emp_id": 1129,
    "emp_name": "Kevin",
    "department": "Sed",
    "skills": [
      {
        "skillset": "AWS",
        "experience": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting an error :  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-4c54e635eb12> in <module>()
      5 df=result
      6 
----> 7 j = (df.groupby(['emp_id','emp_name','department'], as_index=False)
      8        .apply(lambda x: x[['skillset','experience']].to_dict('r'))
      9        .reset_index()

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: emp_id emp_name department skills
1120
Gary
Lobortis
skillset experience
java
7
python
1
Analytics
7
1122
Prescott
Velit
skillset experience
Oracle
3
java
3
1129
Kevin
Sed
skillset experience
AWS
7